# superposing curves with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a series of curves to make the image like a video by using this script:

```
from pylab import *
a = 1
L = 3.0
T = 1
dx = 1e-3
dt = 1e-2

NX = int(ceil(L/dx))
NT = int(ceil(T/dt))

X  = np.linspace(-L,L, NX)
U0 = 1./sqrt(2*np.pi)*np.exp(-X**2/2)
Un = U0
Unext = zeros(NX)
line, = plot(X,U0)
show()

for n in range(NT):
    Unext[1:-2] = 1./2*(Un[2:-1]+Un[0:-3])
    Unext[1:-2] += -a*dt/2*dx*(Un[2:-1]+Un[0:-3])
    Un = Unext
    line.set_ydata(Un)
    draw()
```

But the problem is that I have the first one only.  Can some one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

`plot` returns a `Line2D`, which you are updating the y-data on each time through the loop.  If you want to see *all* of the curves, call plot each time through the loop:

```
for n in range(NT):
    Unext[1:-2] = 1./2*(Un[2:-1]+Un[0:-3])
    Unext[1:-2] += -a*dt/2*dx*(Un[2:-1]+Un[0:-3])
    Un = Unext
    plot(X, Un)
    draw()
```

If you are trying to fake animation, you need to add a `pause` so you can see each updated line:

```
for n in range(NT):
    Unext[1:-2] = 1./2*(Un[2:-1]+Un[0:-3])
    Unext[1:-2] += -a*dt/2*dx*(Un[2:-1]+Un[0:-3])
    Un = Unext
    line.set_ydata(Un)
    draw()
    plt.pause(.1)
```

Also, your curves are almost identical for this range.